# SQL count query, not al dates are every time in the table

Tags: sql

I have a query that I can't figure out. I have the following table and would like to have the following result.

The Enforcement_date column is not always filled, but I would like to compare/count it per subname. So with subname A-1 the Enforcement_date is filled in 1 of the 3 lines. I would then like to compare all those 3 lines whether the date in Returned < is the date in Enforcement_date (count: Returned < Enforcement_date)

In addition, I would also like to calculate the Enforcement_date + 1 month and then compare this month with the date at returned (count: Returned < Enforcement_date+1month)

| ID | Projectname | Subname | Exp_return_date | Returned | Enforcement_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A-1 | 1-4-2023 | 28-1-2023 |  |
| 2 | A | A-1 | 1-4-2023 |  | 01-05-2023 |
| 3 | A | A-1 | 1-4-2023 | 28-4-2023 |  |
| 4 | A | A-2 | 1-7-2023 | 10-8-2023 | 2-8-2023 |
| 5 | A | A-2 | 1-7-2023 | 28-6-2023 |  |
| 6 | A | A-2 | 1-7-2023 |  | 2-8-2023 |
| 7 | B | B-1 | 1-3-2023 | 04-04-2023 | 1-4-2023 |
| 8 | B | B-1 | 1-3-2023 | 02-03-2023 |  |
| 9 | B | B-2 | 1-6-2023 | 28-5-2023 |  |
| 10 | B | B-2 | 1-6-2023 | 3-6-2023 |  |

| Project | Subname | ED | Count | <=exp_return_date | <enforcement_date | eforncement_date_+1_month | None |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A-1 | 01-05-2023 | 3 | 1 (all before 01-04-2023) | 2 (all before 01-05-2023) | 2 (all before 01-06-2023) | 1 |
| A | A-2 | 02-08-2023 | 3 | 1 (all before 01-07-2023) | 1 (all before 02-08-2023) | 2 (all before 02-09-2023) | 1 |
| B | B-1 | 01-04-2023 | 2 | 0 (all before 01-03-2023) | 1 (all before 01-04-2023) | 2 (all before 01-05-2023) | 0 |
| B | B-2 |  | 2 | 1 (all before 01-06-2023) |  |  | 0 |

```
SELECT [Project], [Subname], MIN(Enforcement_date) as ‘ED’,
COUNT(*) as 'Count', 
COUNT(case when Returned <= Exp_return_date then 1 else null end) as ‘<= Exp_return_date’,

COUNT(case when Returned <= Enforcement_date then 1 else null end) as ‘< Enformcement_date’, ***-> didn’t works, Enforcement_date is not always entered.***
COUNT(case when Returned <= Enforcement_date+1month then 1 else null end) as ‘< Enformcement_date’, ***-> how can I calculated this?***

COUNT(case when Returned <> '' then 1 else null end) as ‘None’

FROM *******
GROUP BY [Project], [Subname]
```

Try en error. reading the forum/forums

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to share the enforcement date over all the rows for each subname. A way to do that is by using a "window function" as seen here. Run this to see the effect:

```
  select
        *
      , min(Enforcement_date) over(partition by Subname) as min_ed
  from your_table
```

Once each row has access to that date then the subsequent calculations are possible. e.g:

```
select
      Projectname
    , Subname
    , min_ed
    , COUNT(*) AS "Count"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Returned <= Exp_return_date THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "<= Exp_return_date"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Returned <= min_ed THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "< Enformcement_date"
from (
  select
        *
      , min(Enforcement_date) over(partition by Subname) as min_ed
  from your_table
  ) d
group by
      Projectname
    , Subname
    , min_ed
```

| Projectname | Subname | min_ed | Count | <= Exp_return_date | < Enformcement_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A-1 | 2023-05-01 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| A | A-2 | 2023-08-02 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| B | B-1 | 2023-04-01 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| B | B-2 | *null* | 2 | 1 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KT98ygsA)